# trouble reaching a css node

Tags: css, r, rvest

from this page:
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/app/buscador/default.html?q=e15a61a

i'm trying to retrieve this url:
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/app/biblioteca/ficha.html?upc=702825720599,

I've tried to reach it through the css selector and through the xpath (copied with right-click in web developer tab), however, I only get an {xml_nodeset (0)]

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/app/buscador/default.html?q=e15a62b"
url %>% html_node("#snippet_row-tag_a_0") 
url %>% html_node(xpath='//*[@id="snippet_row-tag_a_0"]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items you want to scrape are rendered with JavaScript, you can use the hidden API instead:

Try this url:
`http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/app/api/buscador/busquedaTodos/E15A61A_A/RANKING/es`

This will return you a JSON string, you can parse it into a list in R and extract the information you want.

Comment: how did you find that hidden API?

Comment: You can find that in network tab using Chrome's developer tools.