# Unable to scrape financial data off Morningstar using rvest and Selector Gadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, finance, rvest

First time trying to scrape some financial data off Morningstar's website.

Specifically, I am trying to scrape the Free Cash Flow Per Share data for the following company: [Hongkong Land Holdings](http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=H78)

I have used Selector Gadget to highlight the data which I want. The following screenshot shows what I have done.

[image: Hongkong Land Selector Gadget]

I tried using the following R script to get the Free Cash Flow per share data. However, the list that returns from the `html_nodes` function is a list of 0. I have tried using the css from Selector Gadget as well as the xpath. Both methods did not yield the desired result.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=H78"

webpage <- read_html(url)

FCF_per_share <- html_nodes(webpage, css = "#i90 , tr:nth-child(28) td, :nth-child(7) :nth-child(11) :nth-child(6) :nth-child(5) :nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4)")

FCF_per_share <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = "//*[(@id = "i90")] | //tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 28) and parent::*)]//td//*[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 7) and parent::*)]//*[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 11) and parent::*)]//*[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 6) and parent::*)]//*[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 5) and parent::*)]//*[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 3) and parent::*)]//td[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 4) and parent::*)]")
```

I tried looking at my webpage variable above. It is a list of 2. When I tried to use the square brackets on the webpage variable, I am given the following results (am unsure what it means and whether is it correct):

```
webpage[[1]]
<pointer: 0x07928060>
webpage[[2]]
<pointer: 0x0778adc8>
```

Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webscraping soccer data returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025719/webscraping-soccer-data-returns-nothing)

Comment: The same issue, the value is generated using JavaScript. Use Rselenium instead.

Comment: @YifuYan Thanks for the link. I do not have experience with Rselenium yet, hence I can't reach a solution just yet. As I am unfamiliar with JavaScript, could I confirm with you that if I encounter any website with JavaScript tags within its source code, I should not use rvest and go straight to using Rselenium? Thanks!

Comment: You can absolutely use `rvest`, but that requires more techniques. For example,you can use the hidden api in that website:`http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1529983223636&t=XSES:H78&region=sgp&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1529983223703`

Comment: You can see my other answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997094/trouble-reaching-a-css-node